# How to use data-remote in bootstrap validator?

Tags: laravel-4

I am using [bootstrap validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) to validate my form with Laravel. Somehow I can't get it right. Can anyone show me a simple example how to use this thing?

Answer (score 1):

Use [formvalidation](http://formvalidation.io) you can get from [Github](https://github.com/formvalidation/formvalidation)

Copy `dist` and `vendor` Folders to inside **PUBLIC** path in Laravel.

To apply to any view **Follow This Order**

**CSS**

```
<head>
 {{ HTML::style('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}
 {{ HTML::style('dist/css/formValidation.css') }}
</head>
```

**JS**

```
<body>
 {{ HTML::script('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('dist/js/formValidation.js') }}
 {{ HTML::script('dist/js/framework/bootstrap.js') }}
</body>
```

**Recommended**

Put Css and Js links in master.blade.php then use following code in any view!

```
@extends('master') 
@stop)
```

**Example of use:**

```
@extends('master')

{{ Form::open(['route'=>['sample.store'],'id'=>'sampleForm']) }}

{{ Form::label('title','Title',['class'=>'col-md-3 control-label'])}}
{{ Form::text('title', null, ['class'=>'form-control col-md-4','placeholder'=>'Title'])}}

{{ Form::close() }}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sampleForm').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                title: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The title  is required'
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@stop
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was hoping for the example of data-remote from bootstrap validator by 1000hz not formvalidation.